# Deleting a file and delete its name from a list

Tags: android, list, sqlite, android-sqlite, delete-file

I am trying to delete files from a list view, I am able to delete the original file but not to delete the name from the list, I think its because I need to delete it from the database, problem is I don't know how, could somebody help?

// the adapter

```
        listAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(RecordsActivity.this, R.layout.support_simple_spinner_dropdown_item, MainActivity.listRecord);
    recordList.setAdapter(listAdapter);
```

//deleting the file (which goes well, the name is not deleted from the database I guess)

```
        delete.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            try {
                datadelete(filePath);
                listAdapter.remove(recordToPlay);
                listAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                delete.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                share.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "File deleted successfully", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
    });
```

// The dataDelete method

```
    public void dataDelete(String inputPath) throws FileNotFoundException {
    try {
        // delete the original file
        new File(inputPath).delete();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("tag", e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

//Main Activity

```
            File directory = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + File.separator + "/Recordings");
        directory.mkdirs();

        //outPutFile = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString() + "/recording.3gp";
        String dateTime = new SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM.yyyy  hh-mm-ss aa", Locale.getDefault()).format(new Date());
        //Date date = new Date();
        //String dateTime = DateFormat.getDateTimeInstance().format(date);
        outPutFile = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/Recordings/"+dateTime +".m4a";

        final String DIR_DATABASE = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/Recordings";
        String sqliteQuery = "CREATE  TABLE  IF NOT EXISTS Recordings (ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY  AUTOINCREMENT  NOT NULL  UNIQUE , fileName VARCHAR)";
        database = SQLiteDatabase.openOrCreateDatabase(DIR_DATABASE + "db.sqlite", null);
        database.execSQL(sqliteQuery);

        getNames();
```

// The getNames method for retrieving the names of the files

```
    public static void getNames(){
    Cursor cursor = database.rawQuery("SELECT fileName FROM Recordings", null);
    ArrayList<String> fileNames = new ArrayList<>();
    while (cursor.moveToNext()) {

        String fileName = cursor.getString(0);
        fileNames.add(fileName);
    }
    cursor.close();
    database.close();

    listRecord.addAll(fileNames);
}
```

// And this is where I save the files

```
            stop.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                mediaRecorder.stop();
                mediaRecorder.release();
                mediaRecorder = null;
                stop.setEnabled(false);
                pauseBtn.setEnabled(false);

                SQLiteDatabase database = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(DIR_DATABASE + "db.sqlite", null, 0);
                values = new ContentValues();
                values.put("fileName", outPutFile.substring(31));
                database.insert("Recordings", "", values);


                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Audio recorded", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                Activity mActivity = MainActivity.this;
                restartActivity(mActivity);


            }
        });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add a delete query to delete data from the database. Change your code in to

```
delete.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        try {
            datadelete(filePath);
            database = this.getWritableDatabase();
            database.execSQL("DELETE FROM Recordings WHERE fileName = '"+your file name Here+"'");
            database.close();
            listAdapter.remove(recordToPlay);
            listAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

            delete.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            share.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "File deleted successfully", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
});
```

You should write the filename which you want to delete in the sqlite query. Hope this will work.